# Cant synch with Outlook

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook

I had no problems with the synch until a week ago and now I am getting this error:

id length is not of valid length 
Parameter name: id.

[image]

Nothing is synching now.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It could be because of corrupt sync database. I had a similar problem like yours and followed the steps provided in the article - https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h09CAAQ. Renaming the DB really helped.
I hope it helps.